# how to write a chunk data to a file

Tags: node.js, filestream

When client posts a chunk data(part of file), then server side should insert the chunk to file.
But fs.open will truncate the file. So I cant use empty fd to write.
Now this is what I am using it reads all buffer and changes the chunk range value in the buffer.

```
    //badly code
fs.open(getFilePath(fileId),"r+",function(err,fd){
    var bytes = new Buffer(metadata.fileSize);
    fs.read(fd,bytes,0,bytes.length,0,function(){
        for(var i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
            if(i>=start && i <= end){
                bytes[i] = buffer[i-start];
            }
        }
        //console.log(bytes);
        fs.write(fd,bytes,0,bytes.length,0,function(err){
            if(err) throw err;

            fs.close(fd,function(){
                metadata.addChunk(start,end);
                metadata.save(callback);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a better method to do this? Please tell me,thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question might be a bit outdated but I faced the same problem, while trying to get source code to a file
To solve this I did not use write file but append, for example:

```
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      fs.appendFile('body.txt', chunk, function (err) {
          if(err) throw err;
      });
```

This worked pretty fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to append http requests to a file.

Open an appending write stream.

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'a'});
```

Then in your http handler

```
function (req, res) {
  req.pipe(writeStream, {end: false});
  req.on('end', function () {
    res.end('chunk received');
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks,If I dont append instead of use position, this method can do well? I have tried to using createWriteStream(path,{poistion:x,start:y,size:z}) stream.write(buffer);  it will overwrite content.